# How to chance value of bool after recent time installing app for first time?

Tags: android, xml, boolean, dashboard

Hi I'm using a dashboard source for my wallpapers app, there option to enable or disable to download wallpapers in configuration xml like this :

```
<bool name="enable_wallpaper_download">true</bool>
```

but is it possible to set it to false by default and then to change it true after 24 hours installing the app for first time?